# Openbravo POS - adding new button

Tags: java, swing, openbravo

I am working on Openbravo POS 2.30 (Java desktop application) and now I need to add some window, button, process etc.

Online documentation for developers is very weak, and I am also new to Java, 
so basically I am stuck.
I have looked all day to code, but whatever I add I can't manage to show that on application.
I've also tried to add some simple report (following http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Openbravo_POS_Reports_and_Charts_Tutorial#The_reports_architecture_in_Openbravo_ERP) but I am missing the step how to add new button to call this report...

Can anyone help me where to start?

Comment: Their public API is here http://code.openbravo.com/docs/ It doesn't go back to 2.30. What do you mean by add the button? You mean that you're looking for the code that would actually generate the report?

Comment: This is API for Openbravo ERP, I am working on Openbravo POS :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an entry to menu.root in resource table for class file from where you can call this report. look at menu.root you will get to know.